# Calculate end to end time for a series of kinesis streams followed by lambdas

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis

We have a system that takes in an input record and applies a series of transformations using series of kinesis streams and lambdas operating on it.

KinesisStream --> InputRecord --> Lambda1/Lambda2 running in parallel --> Output1 Kinesis Stream --> Lambda3 --> Output2 Kinesis Stream --> store into DynamoDB

Lambda cloudwatch documentation @ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions.html gives details on time taken per lambda metrics.

However, we would like to also get the metrics on total time taken for an input record to flow through the entire chain.

Has anyone done something similar to collect end-to-end latency?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the latency per event in the last lambda (or in the Updates Stream of DynamoDB, if you also want to calculate that part).

For example, in Lambda3 in your example, you can read a timestamp that you put on your records or the timestamp of Kinesis, calculate the `diff` from `now`, and write it to the `console.log`. These logs are written to CloudWatch Logs, where you can define your metric and show it in CloudWatch and even generate an Alarm to notify you when this latency is higher than your SLA threshold.